# Execute plugin functionality after application config/startup

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I'm developing a grails plugin, which I would like to send an email after the application's `Config.groovy` has been processed. (For one reason, that the `Config.groovy` - or other external configuration file - will have all the config I need for emails.)

I attempted a `MyPluginBootStrap.groovy`, however this got executed before the applications configuration (and indeed, its `BootStrap.groovy`). And it seems all the normal plugin `onXXX()` hooks are executed before the application startup.

My next thought is simply to tell people that they need to manually call a method in the plugin to trigger the functionality. So, they'd potentially add a call to their `BootStrap.groovy`. But I want it more automatic.

Ideally I'd like things to work as follows:

1. A developer adds the plugin to their `BuildConfig.groovy`;
2. A developer specifies some configuration in their `Config.groovy` - or external config; and then
3. When you app starts, the email gets sent - without them having to do anything more than item 1 and 2 above.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why not create a service that is included in your plugin and have it implement the `org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean` interface and the `afterPropertiesSet` method to send the email? Of course this would happen every time the application is run.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore thanks for that. Gave it a go and realised it runs just before the plugin's bootstrap; and that it wont get executed unless it's injected into something - for which bootstrap is really the only suitable option. So in the end, I've simply used the plugin's boostrap (which turns out does have access to the app's config). Just a shame it gets executed before their bootstrap - but they can call the service method manually if they want it otherwise.